# How i can compare Two input values at the time of validation

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation

when I submit the form, I want to compare two input values at the time of validation in Controller store function

```
array(
'name' => 'required',
'password' => 'required|min:8',
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
'rule'=>'input1'<'input2',
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your `rule` property is not really an input field on the form or data. Because if `rule` is a property, like email, then I don't know what you want to validate it against. (`rule` is only valid if `input1` is smaller than `input2`?)

Maybe you actually want to validate the `input1` attribute like this:

```
array(
    'name' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required|min:8',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'input1'=> 'lt:input2',
)
```

Do mind that `input1` and `input2` must be of the same type.
See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-lt